# Display data in refinery through an API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

I am using `Refinery CMS` version 2. I want to display the data through an `Api call` from another project. I want to know how much refinery support this and how. Also i want to use different menu for different pages then how should i do that? I ve used the `refinerycms-menu` gem but those menus are displayed in all the pages. How to restrict particular menu for particular page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For display `another menu` in some other i just did this in my `layout/application.html.erb

```
<% if request.fullpath == "/PATH" -%>
    <%= render "/refinery/NAME_OF_ANOTHER_MENU" -%>
<% else %>
<%= render "/refinery/header" -%>
<% end %>
```

I created another `menu` by using `gem refinerycms-menus'.

For `api call` i am still searching.

Thanks :-)